# Ports required to open for Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

In my company, a few ports are blocked and I am unable to identify a list of ports to tell my IT team to whitelist.

I am using Visual Studio 2015.

The reason why I am being so specific on ports is that, these steps I have followed at my home machine & I found no issues. The problem is only in my company due to Proxy/Port/Firewall.

Steps followed:

1. I have created a sample MVC Web application & kept authentication as default (Individual User Accounts).

[image]

2. After creating this application, I right-clicked on the project & clicked on Configure Azure AD Authentication & followed the steps properly.

[image]

3. I created a few users in Azure Portal and ran the application which is working fine.
4. Then I deployed the application on my local IIS by changing connectionstring (which got created in Step 2) from localDB to SQLExpress
5. The application isn't working after deploying on local IIS in my company but working on my home machine.

I am unable to identify the ports/proxy settings which I need to tell my company to whitelist.

Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: How about running [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see the traffic, especially the traffic that fails?

Comment: I tried running fiddler but nothing fails in it so I am unable to understand the ports.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Hybrid Identity Required Ports and Protocols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-ports) documentation, find your scenario and see the ports needed for that.

> The following document is a technical reference on the required ports and protocols for implementing a hybrid identity solution. Use the following illustration and refer to the corresponding table.

Comment: I have gone through this article and scenario 5 suits my application so I have opened the respective ports but still it's not working